# using excel VBA generate a table of numbers counting anti clock wise with 1 in the middle

Tags: excel, vba

using excel VBA i have to generate a table of numbers counting anti clock wise with one in the middle and highlight prime numbers in red in the process the following image is an example of the out put i should have .

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response,  i have never used vba before so what i have will just confuse people as it is not even close to what i need

Comment: Thats okay, but SO is *no* code writing service. You should read a basic VBA tutorial like [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/) and try to solve your problem on your own. If a question occurs, you are welcome to ask it on SO. In this case make sure you add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sample code for you to start with,

```
Sub primeNum()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
Dim l As Long
j = 50
x = 20
y = 20
k = 1
i = 1
Cells(x, y) = 1
Loops:
    For z = 1 To 4
        If z = 3 Then
            k = k + 1
        End If
        For l = 1 To k
        i = i + 1
        Select Case (z)
        Case "1":
            y = y + 1
            Cells(x, y) = i
        Case "2":
            x = x - 1
            Cells(x, y) = i
        Case "3":
            y = y - 1
            Cells(x, y) = i
        Case "4":
            x = x + 1
            Cells(x, y) = i
        End Select
        Next l
    Next z
    k = k + 1
    If i <= j Then
    GoTo Loops
    End If
End Sub
```

I leave the part of checking prime numbers for you to google and find,

[image]

Comment: thank you very much this will definitely take me somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you guys i have used the above code to come up with this code which works perfectly.

```
Option Explicit
Private Function GetPrime(MaxToCheck As Long) As Collection
Dim c As New Collection, isUnDivided As Boolean, i As Long, v
c.Add Key:="2", Item:=2
For i = 3 To MaxToCheck
  isUnDivided = True
  For Each v In c
      If i Mod v = 0 Then isUnDivided = False: Exit For
  Next v
  If isUnDivided Then c.Add Key:=CStr(i), Item:=i
Next i
Set GetPrime = c
End Function
Sub prime()
Dim a, c As New Collection, i As Long, j As Long, r As Range, v
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
a = .Value
Set c = GetPrime(Application.Max(a))
For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
           v = c(CStr(a(i, j)))
           If Err.Number = 0 Then
              If Not r Is Nothing Then Set r = Union(r, .Cells(i, j)) Else 
 Set r = .Cells(i, j)
           End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next j
Next i
End With
If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Font.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```